# Redundant constructor overloads in std::function?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, c++14, std-function

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), `std::function` has the following three constructor overloads:

```
template< class Alloc > 
function( std::allocator_arg_t, const Alloc& alloc, 
          const function& other );
template< class Alloc > 
function( std::allocator_arg_t, const Alloc& alloc, 
          function&& other );
template< class F, class Alloc > 
function( std::allocator_arg_t, const Alloc& alloc, F f );
```

Wouldn't it be sufficient to just leave the last one? Would the first two provide any better performance (they are more specialized, anyway)? If so, how could it be done?

Comment: The third version would at least have to take `f` as a forwarding reference.

Comment: @nwp Agreed. But it's specified so in the standard. There got to be a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: It's an optimization

The first two versions take `std::function`s as arguments whereas the third version takes an arbitrary callable. Taking an arbitrary callable requires type erasure, so you end up with a function call overhead when calling an `std::function` and possibly a dynamic memory allocation for creation.

Removing the first two overloads would make `std::function` treat another `std::function` as a generic callable and type-erase that function, so you would end up with an `std::function` calling an `std::function` calling an `std::function` and possibly pay dynamic memory allocation each time.

Instead you treat `std::function` differently and instead of storing the `std::function` you just store the callable that the other `std::function` stores, thereby reducing the levels of indirection and dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think nwp does get a point. If you have any insight into this issue, please share it with us :)

Comment: @Lingxi: nwp is spot on; didn't say otherwise.